# Crear consulta en varias tablas con Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

Quiero impedir que el usuario borre un registro si este se encuentra ya en uso ejemplo:
Tabla Paciente-id_paciente tenga interacción con tabla Accidentes o Tabla Citas
Claro por la llave primaria id_paciente.

La idea es que si tiene ya registros no se elimine, pero si no tiene que el usuario lo elimine.
 Lo estoy tratando de realizar por medio de deshabilitar el botón de eliminación, pero no encuentro como armar la condición para que me funcione como debería.

Mi codigo es este:

```
<td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('pacientes.edit',$paciente->id_paciente) }}" title="Editar"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></a>
            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['pacientes.destroy', $paciente->id_paciente],'style'=>'display:inline','onsubmit' => 'return ConfirmDeleteModel("el paciente","'.$paciente->nombre_pac.'","'.$paciente->id_paciente.'")']) !!}
            @if ($paciente->hacer_condicion)
            <button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' value='submit' title="Borrar" disabled='false'>      <span class='fas fa-times'> </span>
                </button>
                @else
                <button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' value='submit' title="Borrar" >      <span class='fas fa-times'> </span>
                    @endif

            {!! Form::close() !!}

    </td>
```

funciona para eliminar un registro sin mas interaciones pero al querer eliminar un paciente que ta tiene accidente o cita no puedo desabilitar el boton

Espero y me puedan orientar soy relativamente un Novato en laravel aun no lo comprendo bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras: mediante claves ajenas en base de datos que enlacen las tablas e impidan eliminar registros ya enlazados o, por código, comprobando antes del borrado del registro. También te digo que las dos maneras pueden convivir al mismo tiempo, no son excluyentes

**Claves ajenas**

Para el primer caso, basta con que las definas sin poner nada como acción en el delete. Por ejemplo, si tenemos dos tablas: `pacientes` y `citas`, suponiendo que se unen por el campo `id_paciente`, la clave ajena en MySQL se definiría así:

```
ALTER TABLE pacientes ADD CONSTRAINT fk_citas_pacientes FOREIGN KEY (id_paciente) REFERENCES citas (id_paciente);
```

Tendrías que poner algo de código para tratar esta excepción al eliminar el paciente en el controlador para mostrar un mensaje más amigable al usuario

**Mediante código**

En este caso tienes muchas opciones pero voy a detallar una:

1. Relacionamos los modelos Paciente y Cita mediante hasMany y belongsTo:

> Modelo Paciente

```
public function citas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cita');
}
```

> Modelo Cita

```
public function paciente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Paciente');
}
```

2. En el controlador, en el método que elimina un paciente, comprobamos si tiene citas:

> Controlador PacienteController

```
if ($paciente->citas()->count() != 0) {
    // No dejamos eliminar y nos salimos
}
```

3. En la vista, no mostramos el botón de eliminar si el paciente tiene citas:

> Vista Paciente

```
@if ($paciente->citas()->count() == 0) 
    <button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' value='submit' title="Borrar" disabled='false'><span class='fas fa-times'></span></button>
@endif
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya tenia implementado casi todo lo que me mencionaste solo me faltaba armar bien la condicion en la vista. ahora solo agrego un if anidado para ambas tablas.